# how to determine past perfect tense from POS tags

Tags: nltk, spacy

The past perfect form of 'I love.' is 'I had loved.' I am trying to identify such past perfects from POS tags (using NLTK, spacy, Stanford CoreNLP). What POS tag should I be looking for? Instead .. should I be looking for past form of the word have .. will that be exhaustive?

`I PRP PRON
had VBD VERB
loved VBN VERB
. . PUNCT`

Answer (score 1):

The complete POS tag list used by CoreNLP (and I believe all the other libraries trained on the same data) is available at https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html

I think your best best is to let the library annotate a list of sentences where you want to identify a specific verbal form and manually derive a series of rules (e.g., sequences of POS tags) that match what you need. For example you could be looking for `VBD` ("I loved"), `VBD VBN` ("I had loved"), `VBD VBG` ("I was loving somebody"), etc...